# Loan Repayment Schedule

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I want to make a repayment schedule on oracle.

Here I have created two table

**Fund_disburse**

```
create table fund_disburse
(
area_code       CHAR (2),
branch_code     char (5),
comp_code       CHAR (3),
dafa_no         CHAR (2),
disburse_date   date,
fund_amt        NUMBER (20,2),
sc_amt          NUMBER(15,2),
Inst_start_date     date,
Inst_end_date   date,
TTL_INST_NO_PAID    NUMBER (2),
TTL_INST_AMT_PAID   NUMBER (20,2),
ttl_outs        number (20,2) ,
ttl_overd       number (20,2),
ttl_adv         number (20,2), 
ful_pay_flag    CHAR(1)) ;

CONSTRAINT "FUND_DISBURSE_PK"
  PRIMARY KEY ("AREA_CODE", "BRANCH_CODE", "COMP_CODE", "DAFA_NO")
```

**Fund Repay Schedule**

```
create table f_repay_schedule
(
area_code     CHAR (2),
branch_code   char (5),
comp_code     CHAR (3),
dafa_no       CHAR (2),
Install_no    NUMBER (2),
Install_date  date,
MNYR          VARCHAR2 (8),
Install_amt   NUMBER (20,2),
prn_amt       NUMBER (15,2),
sc_amt        NUMBER (12,2));

CONSTRAINT "F_REPAY_SCHEDULE_FK1"
  FOREIGN KEY ("AREA_CODE", "BRANCH_CODE", "COMP_CODE", "DAFA_NO")
  REFERENCES "RINFO"."FUND_DISBURSE" ("AREA_CODE", "BRANCH_CODE", "COMP_CODE", "DAFA_NO")
```

When I will insert on fund_disburse , the repayment schedule will generate in f_repay_schedule table . How can I do that ?

I have also tried to do that by  plsql, as like ,

```
declare 
  k NUMBER := 0;
  DISBURSE_AMOUNT number (10) :=&DISBURSE_AMOUNT;
  TTL_LOAN_AMT NUMBER (10) := DISBURSE_AMOUNT*1.13;
  DAILY_RCVL number (10) := DISBURSE_AMOUNT/1000*25;
  PRN_AMT NUMBER (10) := DAILY_RCVL/1.13;
  SC_AMT NUMBER (10) := DAILY_RCVL - PRN_AMT;
  lAST_INS_AMT NUMBER (10) := TTL_LOAN_AMT - DAILY_RCVL*45;
  INST_NO NUMBER (2) := 0;
  INST_DATE DATE := SYSDATE;
begin 
  loop
    k := DAILY_RCVL +0; 
    TTL_LOAN_AMT := TTL_LOAN_AMT - DAILY_RCVL;
    INST_NO := INST_NO +1;
    INST_DATE := INST_DATE + 7;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('DATE '||INST_DATE);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('INSTALLMWNT NO '||INST_NO);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(' Daily RCV '||k);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('PRINCIPLE AMOUNT: '||PRN_AMT);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('SERVICE CHARGE: '||SC_AMT);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Loan AMOUNT AFTER RCV: '||TTL_LOAN_AMT);

    EXIT WHEN TTL_LOAN_AMT < DAILY_RCVL;
  END LOOP;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('LAST INSTALLMENT AMT: '|| lAST_INS_AMT);
end;
/
```

But I want to, it will work with those table data.

---

**I have solved my first problem.** 
Now another problem has created . When I try to insert another row on fund disburse
**it shows the error
"exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows"**
 My trigger is

```
create or replace TRIGGER LOAN_RP
  AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON FUND_DISBURSE
  REFERENCING OLD AS NEW OLD AS OLD
DECLARE
  V_FA          NUMBER (10);
  V_RC          NUMBER (10); 
  V_AC          CHAR (2);
  V_BC          CHAR (5);
  V_CC          CHAR (3);
  V_DN          CHAR (2);
  V_PRN         NUMBER (15,2);
  V_SC          NUMBER (15,2);
  V_INSN        NUMBER (2) :=0; 
  V_INSD        DATE;
  V_RAMT        NUMBER (15,2);
BEGIN 
  SELECT AREA_CODE, BRANCH_CODE, COMP_CODE, DAFA_NO, DISBURSE_DATE, FUND_AMT
    INTO V_AC,      V_BC,        V_CC,      V_DN,    V_INSD,        V_FA
    FROM FUND_DISBURSE;

  V_RAMT := V_FA*1.13;
  V_INSD := (V_INSD-7) + 14;

  for i in 1..50 loop
    V_INSD := V_INSD+7;
    V_RC := V_FA/1000*25;
    V_PRN := V_RC/1.13;
    V_SC := V_RC - V_PRN;
    V_INSN := V_INSN + 1;
    V_RAMT := V_RAMT - V_RC;

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(V_RC);
    INSERT INTO F_REPAY_SCHEDULE
     (AREA_CODE, BRANCH_CODE, COMP_CODE, DAFA_NO, INSTALL_NO,    
      INSTALL_DATE, INSTALL_AT, PRN_AMT, SC_AMT)  
    VALUES
     (V_AC,      V_BC,        V_CC,      V_DN,    V_INSN,
      V_INSD,       V_RC,       V_PRN,   V_SC );

    EXIT WHEN V_RAMT < V_RC;
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Comment: This hurts my eyes just looking at it.

Comment: Why  ElGavilan? Anything wrong. Please suggest any correction

Comment: It sounds like you might want a trigger on the Fund_Disburse table. Perhaps that trigger could call a user defined function that could insert into the f_repay_schedule table (using a loop)?

Comment: Well, for starters, you have random parts of your code in different fonts and sizes, making it harder to read. So format your code correctly. Then, take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Sorry for my odd format. I have fixed it.

Yes, Matty M. I need a trigger that will  insert into f_reapy_schedule by geting values from fund_disburse.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a after insert trigger on the Fund_Disburse table - see [here](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/triggers/after_insert.php) for an example. You can then pass the inserted values you need to a user defined function (I believe) - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3855516/how-to-call-pl-sql-function-in-side-a-trigger) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18158894/pl-sql-calling-a-function-inside-a-trigger) for examples. I haven't tested this, but hopefully, it gets you on the right track.

Obviously, the function needs to be created before you can call it inside the trigger.